Vue router suspense triggers the first time but not the second time
so I followed the Vue docs and created a wrapper for the pages so that I can use top-level await. The first time the page is loaded, it works correctly and shows me the spinner. the second time I come back to the page from another page, the spinner is not shown. Instead, I stay on the page until the await call is done then I move to the next page. I was able to fix this by adding a key to the KeepAlive component, but idk if this affects performance or any behaviour, need advice.
<template>
  <div v-if="loadingStore.loading" class="fixed inset-0 z-50 flex items-center justify-center bg-black bg-opacity-30">
    <VaProgressCircle v-if="loadingStore.loading" indeterminate size="10rem" thickness="0.2" />
  </div>
  <RouterView v-slot="{ Component, route }">
    <template v-if="Component">
      <Transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
        <KeepAlive :key="route.path">
          <Suspense>
            <component :is="layout">
              <component :is="Component" :key="route.path" />
            </component>
            <template #fallback>
              <SplashScreen />
            </template>
          </Suspense>
        </KeepAlive>
      </Transition>
    </template>
  </RouterView>
</template>


What is the "store" referred to here? Is that Vuex?

This is complex behaviour that needs to be debugged, consider adding a workable demo

@johnnyaug loadingStore is a pinia store I use to show a loading spinner when I'm making API calls. It's not related to the problem

@EstusFlask I'll do that but it is almost the same thing mentioned on the vue docs, https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense#combining-with-other-components

@itsDanial  The way this behaves relies on the mechanisms that aren't thoroughly documented, both Vue and router. The docs are quite vague on that, "so that they all behave as expected", but the expectations aren't specified. A store itself isn't relevant but the way you change "loading" state may be, considering that you rely on it as an indicator.
